# How to fix Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: no options listed on Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, java, manjaro, deepin

This issues is on Manjaro Deepin 15.9 linux DE. When I run java -version in terminal it outputs this:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:    
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS     
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)    
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

But if the command is run with sudo it outputs it normal **without** the `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:` message !

I managed by placing unset JAVA_OPTIONS in `/etc/environment` , `/etc/profile` and `~.bashrc` to remove the message from terminal. But the message still shows up in Netbeans when I run a project.

Also I run Netbeans as sudo just to check will it show then and it didn’t.
I tried removing some software from Linux which I didn’t need or believe made it was causing the message (because I read the few posts about software being an issue), but nothing changed.

Message not showing in sudo makes me believe maybe root user doesn’t have something installed that normal user has which is producing this message.

This message is visible in live preview of Manjaro Deepin on bootable usb!

Comment: does your regular user have `java` aliased or otherwise wrapped in a function or script? `type -a java` would clarify.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens it does not have, here's the output of the command   
`java is /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/java
java is /usr/bin/java
java is /bin/java
java is /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/java
`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but in case anyone comes across this later...

TL;DR you can't suppress this message. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13863175/4797233 for alternatives.

But why did it only appear sometimes? When you changed users with `sudo` it changed your environment as well, and apparently the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable did not exist in the root user's environment. It also vanished when you removed that variable from your own environment. However, Netbeans can adjust the environment however it wants before creating a Java subprocess, and it is configured to add in this variable whether it was there or not. You should be able to configure Netbeans not to add the variable at all, but the exact steps to do so will depend on your Netbeans version.

Answer (score 0):

Look for all the files in the `environment.d` and `profile.d` directories.

Use this command to check in which file this variable was set. 
In case of my system, it was set in the file
`95kali-themes.conf`.

I used the grep command to check in which it might be stored,
and I found it in the `environment.d` directory:

```
grep "JAVA" /etc/environment.d/*
```

My suggestion is to check all the locations
where the configuration files are located
that are sourced during the initialization of the terminal.